# Медленно выполняются команды через adb

Tags: c#, adb

Я использую c # и advancedADBsharp, для разных действий на андроид через adb. Но все команды выполняются очень медленно, например задержка между командой tap больше секунды. Если вводить команду напрямую через cmd, задержка такая же. Кто нибудь может подсказать как можно сделать выполнение команд быстрее?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А зачем вам всё это? Хочется понять степень специфичности задачи.

Comment: ну может тестирует человек на телефоне. Но большущие задержки - это странно. я бы взял какой-то другой телефон и проверил, если на других будет такая задержка, скорее всего проблема в машине (например, левый антивирус с фаерволом). Если задержка на других телефонах меньше - скорее всего проблема в телефоне (например, на телефоне стоит (точнее лежит) вайбер, который любит занимать картинками все доступное пространство. А телефон от этого тормозить будет жуть как).

Comment: Автоматизирую действия в приложениях, например делаю несколько кликов разных местах без какой либо задержки. Но каждый клик происходит примерно через 2 секунды, что очень медленно.  А поиск элемента через UI Automator Viewer вообще занимает около пяти секунд.

Comment: Да, про устройство забыл, пробовал на разных устройствах и на эмуляторе, везде так же